# Using JSON.stringify in an expression in Angular2 template

Tags: html, angular

I have a small expression to check whether 2 objects are different or not, in order to display this element (via adding class name):

```
<div ngClass='{{JSON.stringify(obj1) != JSON.stringify(obj2) ? "div-show" : ""}}'></div>
```

The problem is I get this error: 
`Cannot read property 'stringify' of undefined`.

What I need a way to work around, or a proper solution if available. Thanks.

PS: I use JSON.stringify() to compare 2 simple objects, nothing fancy here.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

2 Years later but, you can do it the [Angular Way](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) using the built in pipe 'JsonPipe' from @angular/common

```
@Component({
  selector: 'json-pipe',
  template: `<div>
    <p>Without JSON pipe:</p>
    <pre>{{object}}</pre>
    <p>With JSON pipe:</p>
    <pre>{{object | json}}</pre>
    </div>`
})

export class JsonPipeComponent {
  object: Object = {foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux', nested: {xyz: 3, numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}};
}
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: How does the pipe work when using the JSON as a condition for ngClass?  The answer doesn't match what the question is asking about?

Comment: Wow, so elegant!

Answer (score 62):

Template code doesn't have access to all javascript, only component properties and methods.  I think it would be best to create a 'stringify' method on your component, but you could just set a JSON property:

```
public constructor() {
  this.JSON = JSON;
}
```

Also I think your expression is backwards.  [`NgClass`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) takes the css class as the property name and a true/false value to tell whether that class is on the element, and it needs to be in brackets:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'div-show': JSON.stringify(obj1) != JSON.stringify(obj2)}"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your answer and @rashfmnb's are pretty much the same. About the addition, I've experienced many circumstances with `ngClass` and I find my way of doing is the most solid way to use `ngClass`. Of course, yours works perfectly, but in some cases it doesn't, compared to mine. One example that [ngClass] cannot work:
`<div [ngClass]='classNameHolder1' [ngClass]='{"class-name-2": isClassName2}'></div>`. If I'm wrong, feel free to correct me.

Comment: `public JSON : JSON;` field should be defined in the component as well to not break AOT

Answer (score 5):

you can achieve it like this in your **component** do this.

```
myjson:any=JSON;
```

and in you **view** do it like this

```
<div ngClass='{{myjson.stringify(obj1) != myjson.stringify(obj2) ? "div-show" : ""}}'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your code works perfectly but @Jason Goemaat's answer seems to be cleaner to me.

Comment: my friend no problem